# Save Generated File to database PHPWORD

Tags: php, phpword

I'm new with php Programming, I would like to ask if it is possible to save the generated files directly to database if you are using PHP word?

```
$xmlWriter  = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');

$xmlWriter ->save("php://output");
```

Do I need to change the this lines? And I am using php5, mysqli

Comment: you don't want to save on disk, then save to db and then delete from disk?

Comment: is it possible to do that with a click of a button? that it will do 3 things at the same time?

Comment: do you use javascript to call php files or just you are submitting form on button click?

Comment: im just submitting form on button click... what you have in mind i need to use jquery or ajax to do that? please give me an example

Comment: ok, I'll give you my general approach

Comment: is this post solved or not? no answers accepted (yet).

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't possible to save the PHPWord object directly to a database; you can save it to any of PHP's streams, whether that is a file on the server, or to the output stream (browser), but you'd have to write your own code to store it in any database, probably starting by sending the save() output to a file on the server first.

Comment: you mean save the file first to server or local machine? then mysqli code to save to a database? is it possible by to do it in a click of a button.. can u give me an example how to do it? please...

Comment: `starting by sending the save() output to a file on the server first.`

Comment: I tried that but it think it is not good to save it to the server directly.. how about saving the file to temporary folder then some codes to save it to server then unlink the generate document.. however im having a problem how to save it to a temp location

Comment: Why don't you think it's good? It should save to the server perfectly sensibly, whatever filenm, as long as you're saving it to a folder with write permissions

Comment: it is usually a bad form to write in a webtree but if theres nothing we can do. i guess we need to change permission in order to write on that folder

Comment: Well you should have privileges to write to the PHP temp folder (sys_get_temp_dir ()), which shoudn't be inside the web tree, and I don't know many people who consider that is bad practise

Comment: Ive done it thank you all.. will post the exact answer here once everything is in place

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have mysql table `upload_file` with BLOB row where you will store your word file.

For example we have **create-word.php**:

```
$xmlWriter  = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');

$xmlWriter ->save($somePathToUpload.$filename);
```

get contents from generated file by PhpWord:

```
$file = file_get_contents($somePathToUpload.$filename);
```

and use this variable in insert query like:

```
$query= "insert into upload_file(file_blob) values($file)";
```

and then delete generated file from disk:

```
 unlink($somePathToUpload.$filename);
```

**FORM SUBMITTING:**

You can call this **create-word.php** file by form submitting, assume we have some form:

```
<form action='create-word.php'>
     <input type='submit' value='submit'/>
</form>
```

**JQUERY AJAX:**

or you can call **create-word.php** by ajax like that:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'create-word.php',
    type: 'post',
    success: function(response){ // do stuff },
    error: function(error){ console.log(error.responseText); }
});
```

**UPDATE:**

blob insertion more detailed using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php):

```
$file = file_get_contents($somePathToUpload.$filename);
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yourdb", "dbname", "dbpass");
$statement = $pdo->prepare("insert into upload_file(file_name) values(?)");
$statement->bindParam(1, $file);
$statement->execute();
```

also you can watch this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XfobCv4YBdk) for more clearance

Comment: I've tried ur answer it works when you are using local php like xampp, how ever upon trying it in an actual server it wont work.. because of permission to write at the server(which is not ideal).. do you have suggestions on how to save the file in a localmachine then upload and unlink?

Comment: you are not administrator on your server to change permissions of certain directories?

Comment: i can but i prefer not to save it to server just directly to database. but if there is no other way that would be it

Comment: I have not heard if is it possible what you want. I'll try to find something